# Jmeter exception while generating report

Tags: jmeter, robotframework

I am trying to generate html report using robotframework but getting below error

JMeterLibException: 'No samples were found in a log file.'

Command used :

```
Run Jmeter   ${jmeter}    ${jmxPath}  ${logPath}  -JudvData=${excelData} -Jport=${port} -Jurl=${url} -JSMS.group=1
    Analyse Jtl Convert To Html    ${logPath}
```

jtl file is getting generated successfully but facing issue will converting jtl to HTML

Below is the log details ,

[image: Log.html]

Answer (score 0):

If there are no results it means that JMeter script execution has failed somewhere somehow, in this case you can check:

- [Robot Framework log file](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/3.2/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#log-file)
- [JMeter log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

If you cannot figure out what's wrong from the JMeter log file it is possible to increase logging verbosity either for individual components or for the overall application via [log4j2.xml file](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.1/bin/log4j2.xml) (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation), see [How to Configure JMeter Logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) article for more details.

The most common reasons are:

- The number of threads (virtual users) or loops (iterations) in [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) is `0`
- Missing data file referenced in [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)
- Missing [JMeter Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/)

Comment: Getting this error,

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6aCm.png

Comment: I have updated my question with more detail.Please let me know what is the issue here

Comment: The screenshot doesn't add any value, we need [`jmeter.log` file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) (better full) and your [`log.jtl` file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles) (at least first 2-3 lines.

Comment: Hi, below is the log file, 
    https://www.transfernow.net/dl/20210429NBoV7PG4/kylgR3YE

Below is the .jtl content,

1619678537202,1180,Login,200,OK,OutletUpload_MDM 7-1,text,true,,74563,2008,1,1,https://devuitest.bizom.in/users/dashboard,788,0,578
1619678537202,788,Login-0,302,Found,OutletUpload_MDM 7-1,text,true,,1755,713,1,1,https://devuitest.bizom.in//users/login,788,0,578
1619678537998,120,Login-1,302,Found,OutletUpload_MDM 7-1,text,true,,1628,640,1,1,https://devuitest.bizom.in/,120,0,0